# Create polygons with blurred edges (SLD (GeoServer))

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, sld

[image]I would like to create areas from polygons that will visualize an "uncertain" area. So I would like the polygon to appear a little blurred at the edges. Preferably with SLD in GeoServer so that I could get the layer with WMS. I have OpenLayers in frontend so that could be an option as well if its possible that way..

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: GIS SE site prefers focused questions, so you'll have to decide between Geoserver or Open Layers solution, otherwise question will likely to be closed. And picture of such blurred edge would definitely help.

Comment: There are some filter examples in OpenLayers https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-filter.html or perhaps easier a css filter as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/semi-transparent-layer.html (replacing grayscale with blur).

Comment: Thanks. I will try that one

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is currently possible - there is an [old enhancement request](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-6085) that would add gradient functionality to GeoServer but it died from lack of support. If it was revived and funded (with either time or money) you could use a negative buffer on your polygon and a gradient fill.